# Upsetjs component slow with few example data

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use the upsetjs vuejs component but have trouble with it. I use it the same way as in the documentation :

```
<upset-js
  :sets="sets"
  :width="width"
  :height="height"
></upset-js>
```

and define some fake data like this

```
data: function () {
  return {
    elements: [
      { name: 'A', sets: ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'S11', 'S12'] },
      { name: 'B', sets: ['S1', 'S7', 'S6'] },
      { name: 'C', sets: ['S2', 'S7'] },
      { name: 'D', sets: ['S1', 'S3', 'S7'] },
      { name: 'E', sets: ['S1', 'S3', 'S2'] }
    ],
    width: 1500,
    height: 1000
  }
}
```

They provide a function allowing to get the sets from the data

```
computed: {
  sets () {
    return extractSets(this.elements)
  }
}
```

But this is really slow! I use this data test because the data I want to process are much bigger, am I doing something wrong ?